# A local or parameter named 'g' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I'm using Linq `GroupBy` to make groups from my result. Its ok for all of them but I'm getting a strange error when I try to group by `Year` value of the DateTime.

```
   switch (grouping)
         {
             case "country":
                 vix = vi.GroupBy(v => v.User.CountryId).Select(g => g.ToList()).ToList();
                 break;
             case "province":
                 vix = vi.GroupBy(v => v.User.ProvinceId).Select(g => g.ToList()).ToList();
                 break;
             case "city":
                 vix = vi.GroupBy(v => v.User.CityId).Select(g => g.ToList()).ToList();
                 break;
             case "region":
                 vix = vi.GroupBy(v => v.User.RegionId).Select(g => g.ToList()).ToList();
                 break;
             case "education":
                 vix = vi.GroupBy(v => v.User.EducationId).Select(g => g.ToList()).ToList();
                 break;
             case "job":
                 vix = vi.GroupBy(v => v.User.JobId).Select(g => g.ToList()).ToList();
                 break;
             case "gender":
                 vix = vi.GroupBy(v => v.User.Gender).Select(g => g.ToList()).ToList();
                 break;
             case "age":
                 vix = vi.GroupBy(v => v.User.BirthDate.Value.Year).Select(g => g.ToList()).ToList();
                 break;
         }
```

This is the error (Error is only for the last GroupBy which is for age):

> A local or parameter named 'g' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter

Comment: This means that your method uses the variable `g` somewhere prior to this block of code. You need to either refactor this block of code out to a separate method or change your `Select(g => g.ToList())` to something different like `Select(stackoverflow => stackoverflow.ToList())`

Comment: Are you asking what "scope" means?

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible sample? Also what VS version are we talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now I'm not able to verify if this compiles ;-) But what about simplifying the code like this?

```
IGrouping<TypeOfVi> group; // replace with actual type
switch (grouping)
{
    case "country":
        group = vi.GroupBy(v => v.User.CountryId);
        break;
    case "province":
        group = vi.GroupBy(v => v.User.ProvinceId);
        break;
    // and so on...
}
vix = group.Select(g => g.ToList()).ToList();
```

Just try to pull the `Select` out of the switch-case which, by the way, reduces code repetition.

Comment: Well this simplifies my code but does not help with the error

Comment: Well then see Camerons comment above. There must be another variable named g in the same scope.